# Access in .htaccess an environnment variable defined in VirtualHost

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have defined in the apache configuration file an environnment variable in the vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    #...
    SetEnv MY_VAR 123
```

I can access it in my application in PHP:

```
echo $_SERVER['MY_VAR'] //display 123
```

However I can't find a solution to access it in my `.htaccess` in a `RewriteCond`.

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{MY_VAR} "123"
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_VAR} "123"
```

Is this possible ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SetEnvIf` module for this instead of `SetEnv`:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^ MY_VAR=123
```

This will set `MY_VAR` as `123` for any web request.

Then you can use this `RewriteCond` in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_VAR} =123
```

Or using regex:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_VAR} ^123$
```